# Linkable variable type

Tags: c#, variables, ref

Which variable types can be linked? I have tried to use object but it didn't do what I want.

```
object a;
object b;
b = 5;
a = b;
b = 2;
label1.Text = Convert.ToString(a);
```

It writes 5 but I want it to be 2.

Comment: Start by reading [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) on MSDN.

Comment: [Boxing and Unboxing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx) would be a good second page to read through.

Comment: try use pointers and unsafe keyword for main

Comment: in [Value Types and Reference Types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t63sy5hs.aspx) it says "reference types such as Object" so is object a reference type or not?

Comment: Objects tend not to be referenced in c#

Comment: What are you assigning to the `Object`? And _all_ types in C# inherit from Object.

Comment: *However, if you assign a value type to an Object variable, it behaves as if it holds its own data.* - from the same paragraph.

Comment: @Oded: That's not strictly speaking true. Unmanaged pointer types do not inherit from object. Also, there are some strange corner cases. It is strange to say that interface types inherit from object, though it is true that *all types that can implement an interface inherit from object*, so that's perhaps more a philosophical question than anything else. And technically "void" is a struct type and so inherits from object, but you can't use that fact to any advantage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a simple misunderstanding of references and how they work, and what variables are.

```
object a; // a is a storage location
          // it holds references to instances of object

object b; // b is a storage location
          //it holds references to instances of object

b = 5; // "boxes" 5 into an instance of object
       // and assigns reference to that object to b

a = b; // assigns reference in storage location b to storage location a

b = 2; // "boxes" 2 into an instance of object
       // and assign reference to that object to b
```

Think of it like this. `a` and `b` are pieces of paper that hold addresses to homes on them. When you say `b = 5`, think of it as writing down the address to a home `5` on the piece of paper `b`. When you say `a = b`, think of it as *copying* the address that is written on `b` to `a`. When you say `b = 2`, think of it as *erasing* the address that is written on `b` and replacing it with the address to home `2`. **This action does not change the value that is written on the piece of paper `a`.** That's what is happening here.

Now, let's look at a very simple way to make what you're trying to do work.

```
class MyValue {
    public int Value { get; set; }
}

MyValue b = new MyValue { Value = 5 }; 
MyValue a = b;
b.Value = 2;
```

Now, if you say

```
Console.WriteLine(a.Value);
```

what will happen? Let's reason carefully. Again, back to the analogy of `a` and `b` as pieces of paper with addresses written on them. We have said `MyValue b = new MyValue { Value = 5 }`. Think of this as writing down on the piece of paper `b` the address to a home with a sign saying `5` above the front door. Think of `a = b` as *copying* the address that is written on `b` to `a`. And then, think of `b.Value = 2` as changing the value on the sign above the front door, in this case, changing the `5` to `2`. Now, if someone asks, what is the value above the door on the home that has the address that is written on the piece of paper `a`? Well, the address on `a` is the same as the address on `b`. We just changed the value on the sign above the front door from `5` to `2`. So, we expect to see `2`.

Try it, try it, and you will see the value `2` printed to the console.

Think about this over and over and over until you feel it deep in your bones. Until you grasp this fundamental concept, you will find reasoning about programming to be quite challenging.

Comment: Can I link two variables without array?

Comment: @halil12: If you have more questions, start a new question.

Answer (score 5):

Jason's answer is good; to add more to it:

You seem to expect that when you say `a = b` that this means `a` and `b` are now *aliases of the same variable*. That is not what it means; `a = b` means to copy the *contents* of storage location `b` into storage location `a`, not to *relabel* storage location `a`.

There *is* however a way to make two variables alias each other; in fact there are *three* ways to do that in C# (in addition to the technique Jason suggests, which is probably the best).

The first way is to use `ref` and `out` parameters:

```
class P
{
    static object b = 5;
    static void M(ref object a) 
    { 
        b = 2;
        Console.WriteLine(a);
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        M(ref b);
    }
}
```

If you run this you'll see it does what you want. `b` starts as `5`, then the `ref` means that `a` and `b` become aliases. When `b` is changed to `2`, `a` is also because *they are the same variable with two different names.*

However there is no way to do this *inside a single method*.  The underlying runtime does support this and I once made a version of C# that supported:

```
object b = 5;
ref object a = ref b;
b = 2;
// now a is 2
```

But this never made it into the version of the language that shipped to customers.

The second way to make one variable alias another is for advanced programmers only; you can make a pointer which when dereferenced aliases a variable:

```
int b = 5;
int* a = &b;
b = 2;
// Now *a is 2
```

Note that pointer types can only alias variables of "unmanaged types" like `int`, not *managed types* like `object`.

I have been programming advanced C# for ten years and have never had to do this in production code, so I would avoid it if I were you.

The third way to make one variable alias another is for advanced programmers only; you can use the `TypedReference` type and some undocumented features of C# to capture a reference to a variable and then dereference into an alias later. My advice is to not use this feature.

Comment: I wanted to ask just one more question. Can I send an element of an array as ref?

Comment: @halil12: yes; *any* variable can be passed via `ref`. An array element is a variable. The one thing you cannot pass by ref is a *property*; a property with a getter and setter is not actually a variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ValueTypeWrapper<int> a;
        ValueTypeWrapper<int> b;

        // The following line creates a new instance
        // of ValueTypeWrapper<int> by the means of
        // implicit conversion (see last method defined
        // in the ValueTypeWrapper<T> class).
        b = 5;

        // Make the variable "a" point to the same
        // ValueTypeWrapper<int> instance we just created.
        a = b;

        // Now that both variables are pointing to
        // the same *instance*, change the value of
        // the Value property.
        b.Value = 2;

        // Convert.ToString(...) will call
        // ValueTypeWrapper<int>'s ToString()
        // method, which in turn produces the
        // string equivalent of the value inside
        // the Value property.
        // The Value property is equal to 2
        // on both "a" and "b" objects as they
        // point to the same instance.
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(a));
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class ValueTypeWrapper<T> where T : struct
{
    public T Value { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return this.Value.ToString();
    }

    public static implicit operator ValueTypeWrapper<T>(T value)
    {
        return new ValueTypeWrapper<T> { Value = value };
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. I enjoyed it as a purely academic exercise. You should consider marking Jason's post as the answer instead though, as he has gone to some lengths explaining the differences between value and reference types - something you should read carefully and try to absorb.

Comment: It would be good if you just describe the concept a little bit.